# simple Constructor Pattern

Tags: javascript

I have worked with oop style scripting before and trying to get some kind of system with javascript. I wanted to try the most basic pattern, Constructor Pattern.

So I setup one js file called ImageView with a constructor matching the name of the js file.

```
    function ImageView(){
    alert( 'this is working');
}
```

Then I set up another js file called Main.js which will be the main instantiation class.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var imageViewer = new ImageView();
    //ImageView();
});
```

Now what I don't get is I can call this object ImageView without even the new constructor call. For example ImageView(). From what I gather this is just another global function and not a encapsulated class. I'm trying to get away from global crap and separate my methods and properties to their own class. What am I missing her.

Comment: *... get away from global crap ...* - you'll need some patience with javascript.

Comment: Is the question what is the difference between calling it with and without the new?

Comment: Yes sorry maybe the word crap was not a good choice of words. But it is frustrating to have to make everything global. kingjiv the question is how can I encapsulate my code so I can create a new class, that I can have properties and methods that are self contained in an object or class. I have been writing everything in one big js file and trying to keep track of not writhing the same variables twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have already answered what the difference is between using `new` and not using it, so I'll answer your entirely separate question: how do I avoid globals in JS?

The answer is that you can't entirely. You will always have at least one, in which you can stuff your other stuff. So for example if you wanted a "namespace" of `xyz`, you would do:

```
// global:
var xyz = {}; // or, window.xyz = {} if you are in a browser and want to be more explicit.

// "encapsulated" within the xyz "namespace":
xyz.ImageView = function () { alert("This is working"); };
```

There is a better solution: use the emerging concept of JavaScript *modules*. These are not language features (at least not in the current version of JavaScript), so they are really just hacks introduced by very clever libraries that overwrite a couple of global variables to let you avoid creating any more than the ones provided by those libraries. A good example is [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), where you could do something like the following:

```
// In xyz.js, define the xyz module (name automatically derived from filename).
// Whatever is returned from the function you pass to define is "the xyz module"
define(function () {
    return {
        ImageView: function () { alert("This is working"); }
    };
});

// In other code, in a different file, you can say "I require the xyz module
// to do my work," and pass require a function saying "once you've got the xyz module
// for me, here's the work I will do with it".
require(["xyz"], function (xyz) { // dependency array maps to callback arguments
    // I got the xyz module, including the ImageView function it exported. Use it!
    var imageViewer = new xyz.ImageView();
});
```

Here the clever globals RequireJS introduces are the functions `define` and `require`, but if you use them right, you can avoid ever introducing any further globals beside those two.

Comment: Domenic thanks for this, The first example makes sense. Your using a object to trap all your other code inside it. I see what you mean you are still left with the global object. As for the second example I didn't get at all but I'm going to read the info on the link you sent. RequireJS. Thanks again.

Comment: I added some comments to the RequireJS example to hopefully make it clearer what's going on :)

Comment: Domenic thanks again. I'm a little lost so is the class or module called XYZ or ImageView. Maybe I'm getting mixed up between module and class. Maybe they are not the same. So Module sounds like a holder for to self contain your methods and properties. Or am I completely wrong.

Comment: Right, the module is xyz, the class is ImageView. A module holds classes, functions, objects, or whatever---it's job is just to provide a container that keeps things out of the global namespace.

Comment: Do I put my code in define or in require? So where does this all fit into my original js file structure.  ImageView is my seperate js file that will have all my code for manipulating my images. I want to be able to call this classes methods from my main.js file. So with that structure can you explain what define and require does and how to use them. I know I'm missing something that's not clear on how this all relates to my structure.

Comment: `define` defines a new module, so you put code that you want other code to reference there. In your case `ImageView` is part of a "library" that your `main.js` file references, so it goes in `define`, like above. The `main.js` file uses `require` to get a reference to things like `ImageView` defined in that library. It's worth reading the RequireJS docs thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

First off JavaScript doesn't have built in namespaces.  It can only be simulated.  You must also include each javascript file you plan on using.

Your right about just calling `ImageView()`  that basically invokes the constructor on `this` which is next level of scope.

Using `new ImageView()` creates a new Object of constructor ImageView and `this` points to the new instance.

JavaScript is a prototype language with loose typing.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `ImageView`, the value of `this` will be different if you call it with `new`. Without, it's just another function. With `new` it will create a new `ImageView` instance and bind it to the variable `this`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is there a way of stopping the ImageView method from been called globally. The reason is I don't want to have a lot of code and possibly name the same function twice or the same properties twice. Does this mean if I create some properties in my ImageView js class they will also be global?

Comment: @Chapsterj: if you do `this.foo = "bar";` inside the `ImageView` constructor, then if you accidentally forget the `new`, `this` will be bound to the global object (`window` in the browser), so indeed `foo` will end up being global. So... don't forget the `new`! :)